# time complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Hi
I have a question that:

consider I have `T(n) = m * n^2    (n<m)`
is this correct to write `T(n) = O(m)` ?  because I have written `T(n) = m*n*n` So because `n<m` we have `T(n) = O(m)`
thanks

Comment: Are m and n independent variables?  If so, then are you really looking for T(n) or T(m,n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the best thing you can do is to write `T(n,m) = O(m^3)`. `n < m` is a very weak condition and basically just gives you `n in O(m)`. For example, n could always be `m-1`.

**Edit:** My first answer was imprecise, as T was only a function in n. If m is constant, the answer is still holds, but O(m^3) is equal to O(1).

Comment: How you can find constant n0,c0 such that for all n > n0 T(n) <= c0*1? I can say i.e m > n (i.e m is the number of edges in some graph with n node) so the running time of (i.e Kruskal) algorithm which is T(n) = m log n, is O(1). in fact the running time is T(n,m) = ...

Comment: Just set c0 to m^2. However, that only works if m is a constant. Of course, that is somewhat academical. To get some useful information, m should either be a parameter to T or be in some O() of n. However, n<m only gives m \in o(n), which prevents us from giving an upper bound that only depends on n.

Comment: Exactly, So edit your answer your answer is very bad right now, it's like joke.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in this case  T(n) = O(n^2)

The [formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_o_notation#Formal_definition) of big-O:

> f(x) = O(g(x)) if and only if there exists a positive real number M and a real number x0 such that |f(x)| ≤ M|g(x)| for all x > x0.

In your case, T(n) will always be less than or equal to m(n^2).

Comment: which is O(1) for n smaller than some constant m.

Comment: by knowing that n < m, we know m is not fix number, because n is not fix. and you can't find any x0, to have a fix m.

Comment: I believe complexity is a measure of function growth with respect to some variable(s) (in this case n). So according to this you can completely ignore m, because constant doesn't affect function GROWTH or change in terms of n. So +1 for T(n)=O(n^2).

Comment: @0x69, `m` is not constant. m > n.

Comment: In that case question is incorrectly formulated - it should be T(m,n) and not T(n). In such case - complexity would be T(m,n)=O(m,n^2) - this is if m is independent variable. If m is dependent on n, then m must be expressed in terms of n and then T(n) is re-calculated with regards to m=function(n).